# Xamarin Telerik Android Examples

Tags: android, xamarin, telerik

I need to Telerik Xamarin examples (android)
Does anybody know where I can download/get proper examples for this
I want to add the SideDrawer control in my project, but I am struggling to find nice examples.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this link https://github.com/telerik/Android-samples/tree/master/Samples-Xamarin

Or this one http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/  (on the left side you could find the menu with "Getting started", controls and installations etc.)